# CONNECTIONIDLETIME threshold

Tags: db2-luw

I have created a CONNECTIONIDLETIME threshold as follows to force connections that are idle for more than 1 minute, but it does not work. Is there any db or dbm configuration parameter that should be set? OR is there any prerequisite for this threshold to work correctly? My db2 version is v10.5.0.10 on CentOS 6.9

```
CREATE THRESHOLD dbconidl
     FOR DATABASE ACTIVITIES
     ENFORCEMENT DATABASE  ENABLE
     WHEN CONNECTIONIDLETIME > 1 MINUTE 
     STOP EXECUTION
```

Comment: Try to work as user with no system authorizations in the Db2 instance. That is this user must not belong to any group referenced in the SYS*_GROUP instance configuration parameters.

Comment: I have tested it with a user that does not belong to any groups, but it does not work

Comment: Open a Case with IBM support then.